# Rotating repeated measures to wide format in R

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot

I'm trying to do the simplest wide pivot possible and failing to comprehend how to use dplyr::pivot_wide or similar.  I have a data frame that looks like

```
X Y Z ...  K L
x1           l1
x2           l2
x3 .....     l3
```

where x_i is the value of replicate i of X
And I'd like it to look like

```
          X.1 X.2 X.3 Y.1 Y.2 Y.3
Value
```

(single row)

It's simpler than any use case in the examples but I can't figure out the byzantine syntax.  help!

Comment: Hey I'm having a hard time figuring out your example, can you write out the structure of your DF more fully? thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put backticks for formatting!  My bad!!!

Comment: I concur. Could you give us the code to build such a data.frame?

Comment: And the code  you've tried so far?

Comment: Seeing your code might help, since the function is `tidyr::pivot_wider`, not from `dplyr` and not called `pivot_wide`

Comment: @arthur, ```foo = data.frame(a = rnorm(3), b = rnorm(3), c = rnorm(3), d = rnorm(3))```

Comment: Thks. And what do you expect to get from foo?

Comment: A single row looking like ```c(a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, ....)``` with column names something like a.1, a.2, a.3, etc

Comment: Try `foo %>% mutate(key = 1:nrow(foo)) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = key, values_from = c(a,b,c,d))`

Comment: Sorry I don't have code examples, I dont' have anything reasonable right now.  I can reformat the data frame to exactly what I want by as.numeric(data.matrix(foo)) but the column names need to be created appropriately and besides I'd like a more general solution that doesn't rely on the order of array indexing in C

Comment: @qdread, this is exactly it - could you post this separately so that I can mark this as the asnwer?

Comment: Even if you don't have code you think is reasonable, it's unclear what you mean by "can't figure out the byzantine syntax"—what about the syntax is confusing?. Like I said, your description involves 2 different typos, so it's hard/not useful to just guess what the issue is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add a key column first to uniquely identify the original row index of each value in the new one-row data frame, then call `tidyr::pivot_wider()`.

```
library(tidyverse)

foo = data.frame(a = rnorm(3), b = rnorm(3), c = rnorm(3), d = rnorm(3))
foo %>% 
  mutate(key = 1:3) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = key, values_from = a:d)
```

### output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 12
    a_1    a_2    a_3    b_1   b_2    b_3    c_1   c_2   c_3    d_1   d_2    d_3
  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1  1.23 -0.886 -0.313 -0.265  2.04 -0.239 -0.134 0.437  1.01 -0.292 -1.58 -0.498
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to just `unlist(df)` but with some pretty names?

Like

```
my_names<-names(df)
df<-unlist(df)
names(df) <- paste0(repeat(my_names, 3),1:3,sep=".")
```

?

Comment: ... because `pivot_wider` is not made for that **at all**.

Comment: Apparently it is - see qdread's solution.  As I said, I could solve the specific problem with just a dimension cast.  The real reason is to learn the new tidyverse function.  I do like this approach too.  Thanks!